# Is this caulk not intended for use around my tub?

Tags: bathroom, caulk, tub

I am recaulking around the edge of the bathtub where the tub meets the tile on the wall.  I got caulk listed as "for kitchen & bath": Loctite PL(Pro Line) 530.  I haven't used the shower in weeks and finished cleaning the old caulk off.  Reading the directions on the caulk, two things concern me: "*Not Recommended For: ..., tub surrounds,...*" and "*Do not use in areas subject to water immersion*".

I am hoping the first means it isn't meant to structurally hold a tub surround(like one of those molded wall liners).  Maybe the second is saying it's not meant to seal things that would be subject to water pressure, i.e. sealing something that holds water and thus would need to structurally hold under water pressure.

So is this caulk not intended for use around my tub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL 530 is not on [Loctite's website](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/construction-adhesives.shtml)

Are you sure that the number is correct?

Given their products with similar numbers, your tube of 530 is likely an adhesive, not a sealant.  I would not use it except as a last resort in an emergency.  I'd use a tube of sealant instead.

Comment: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-10-fl-oz-PL530-Mirror-Marble-and-Granite-Adhesive-1693636/203438035#.UeNycI0e07w

Comment: You're right I suppose based ont he Home Depot website title, even though no where on the product itself does it have the word "adhesive"...

Comment: label reads like an adhesive. if you can, go with a sealant.

Answer (score 2):

On the PL530 label, under "Performance Facts", 1st box is "Features". It says "Premium grade adhesive formulation specifically for use on mirrors, ..."